# How can we add nested "Repeater" control in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

Need nested "Repeater" control in Elementor.

I was trying to create a custom Elementor widget for team slider. Each team member has social media links. I have set each team member in Repeater control, but I'm unable to set social media links as repeater inside that.

How can we add nested "Repeater" control in Elementor?